# iTextSharp - Adding content to a cell later in the code

Tags: itext

I am using iTextSharp to generate an invoice PDF. For that I wish to display order number and total amount at top of PDF. However the actual amount is calculated during product displaying part.

To make it simple the report follows this structure

===========order number=========
===========total amount=========

//here I display the products and so total amount is calculated here.

==========end of report=========

To achieve this I am creating a cell for total amount like this

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
PdfPCell headingAmountCell = cell;

//add some components to cell, reinitialize them again with new cells etc. 
//but still have first cell reference in headingAmountCell

//calculate total amount here.

.
.
.
.

headerAmountCell.AddElement(new Phrase("Total Amount:" + totalAmount.ToString());

. 
.
.
```

---

However this doesn't work.
I can see order number at top but not total amount.

If you could please help, that'll be great.

Thanks in anticipation.

Regards
Anshul

UPDATE:

Here is a small portion of code to help understand the problem

```
//header
var headerTable = new PdfPTable(logoExists ? 2 : 1);
headerTable.WidthPercentage = 100f;
if (logoExists)
 headerTable.SetWidths(new[] { 50, 50 });

float padding = 5f;
//logo
if (logoExists)
{
var logoFilePath = _pictureService.GetPictureUrl(logoPicture, 0, false);
var cellLogo = new PdfPCell(Image.GetInstance(logoFilePath));
cellLogo.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
cellLogo.BorderColorBottom = BaseColor.GRAY;
cellLogo.PaddingBottom = padding;
cellLogo.VerticalAlignment = Rectangle.ALIGN_TOP;

headerTable.AddCell(cellLogo);

}
//store info
var cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
cell.BorderColorBottom = BaseColor.GRAY;
cell.PaddingBottom = padding;
cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;


//payment method
var paymentMethod = _paymentService.LoadPaymentMethodBySystemName(order.PaymentMethodSystemName);
string paymentMethodStr = paymentMethod != null ? paymentMethod.GetLocalizedFriendlyName(_localizationService, lang.Id) : order.PaymentMethodSystemName;
PdfPCell headingAmountCell = cell;
if (!paymentMethodStr.Contains("COD") && order.PaymentStatus == global::Nop.Core.Domain.Payments.PaymentStatus.Paid)
{
cell.AddElement(new Paragraph("PREPAID", bigFont));
}
else if (paymentMethodStr.Contains("COD") && order.PaymentStatus == global::Nop.Core.Domain.Payments.PaymentStatus.Paid)
{

cell.AddElement(new Phrase("PAYMENT COLLECTED ON DELIVERY", bigFont));

}
else
{
cell.AddElement(new Paragraph("COLLECT ON DELIVERY", bigFont));    
}
string order_number = order.GetOrderNumber();
cell.AddElement(new Paragraph(String.Format(_localizationService.GetResource("PDFInvoice.Order#", lang.Id), order_number), bigFont));
var store = _storeService.GetStoreById(order.StoreId) ?? _storeContext.CurrentStore;

cell.AddElement(new Paragraph(String.Format("Order Date: {0}", _dateTimeHelper.ConvertToUserTime(order.CreatedOnUtc, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToString("D", new CultureInfo(lang.LanguageCulture))), font));
headerTable.AddCell(cell);
doc.Add(headerTable);
//THEN I PERFORM SOME PRODUCT DISPLAY PART WHERE I CALCULATE THE ORDERTOTAL THEN AT THE BOTTOM
//.
//.
..

headingAmountCell.AddElement(new Phrase(Math.Round(orderTotal) + "<-AMOUNT TO COLLECT")));
```

Comment: This question can't be answered as long as we don't see where you add the `PdfPTable` to the `Document`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply.I have added part of code so that you could better understand.

Comment: Er... You do `doc.Add(headerTable)` *before* changing the cell. Meaning you write the table with the cell to the document, **rendering the cell** and *afterwards* you change the content of the cell that is already rendered. It should be no surprise that the content is missing. You need to change the content *before* rendering the table to the document.

Comment: Yes, I thought so later, so I later created a List of objects and added all the tables to that list i.e.

Created a 
`var documentElements = new List<object>();`
and replaced all the doc.Add() statements with
documentElements.Add

and once I added all and modified the content,
I then looped over this list as
foreach(var d in documentElements)
doc.Add((IElement)d);

if doc.Add renders it and I modify everything before adding it to document, this should have worked, but still it doesn't work.

Any reasons why this might not work either?

Comment: That's a different question. Also: why don't you use a page event or a table event to add the grand total? That's what I would have done in the first place...

Comment: Ok,Thanks, I will try that now.